How to run samples/rpmsg_client_sample in Linux?
I am learning RPMSG in Linux, and I found there is a samples/rpmsg_client_sample.c.
I built it into a kernel module, but I don't know how to make its probe function to be called?
And is there any other examples/demos on RPMSG in Linux for my reference?

From what I've been able to find so far, it seems like it should be automatically loaded when an incoming message matches the driver's rpmsg_device_id?  You can check under /sys/bus/rpmsg/drivers to see that it's been registered.
